# Find unique values in two chosen columns on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a UDF for finding unique values combining two columns.

I have a sheet containing data about the employees of my company. I need to count the number of employees of a specific location. Problem is, some employees appear multiple times on a specific location due to the nature of the dataset.

The formula I use for counting the unique cells:

```
IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A1=A1)*($B$1:$B1=B1))>1;0;1)
```

What I want though is to be able to use this function in other sheets whereby I chooses the columns in which to search for values.

I tried to write the formula but, since I am fairly new to VBA, I cannot think of how to get the $-signs in the formula.

Comment: So to cut this short, you want to be able to choose two columns and output the total of unique values when you combine the two columns? Please edit your question to include what you have got so far within VBA, you might still be close.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like the code below, which will let the user select two column on a single Sheet and check how many unique items there are as well as how many duplicate combinations can be found.

The code will prompt the user to select two columns, then it will check the last row with data on each column and assign the data to Arrays, then it will use a Dictionary to record duplicates as an Integer in Items and it will record unique values as Keys.

The code assumes that both Columns will have the same number of rows, some check would be have to be added to make sure that this is the case, else it will only look for combinations for the number of rows of the first selected column:

```
Sub CountUnique()
Dim v1 As Range, v2 As Range
Dim arrFirstCol As Variant, arrSecondCol As Variant
Dim unique As Object
Set unique = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim key As Variant

TryAgain:
Set v1 = Application.InputBox("First list", "Select First Column", Type:=8)
If v1.Columns.Count <> 1 Then GoTo TryAgain
If v1.Rows.Count <> Rows.Count Then GoTo TryAgain
'ensure user selects a full column and not just a range
LastRow = v1.Cells(v1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data in given column
arrFirstCol = Range(Cells(1, v1.Column), Cells(LastRow, v1.Column))
'assign data to Array

TryAgain2:
Set v2 = Application.InputBox("Second list", "Select Second Column", Type:=8)
If v2.Columns.Count <> 1 Then GoTo TryAgain2
If v2.Rows.Count <> Rows.Count Then GoTo TryAgain2
LastRow2 = v2.Cells(v2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
arrSecondCol = Range(Cells(1, v2.Column), Cells(LastRow2, v2.Column))
'
For i = LBound(arrFirstCol) To UBound(arrFirstCol)
    If Not unique.Exists(arrFirstCol(i, 1) & arrSecondCol(i, 1)) Then
        unique.Add arrFirstCol(i, 1) & arrSecondCol(i, 1), 1
    Else
        unique.Item(arrFirstCol(i, 1) & arrSecondCol(i, 1)) = unique.Item(arrFirstCol(i, 1) & arrSecondCol(i, 1)) + 1
    End If
Next

For Each key In unique.Keys
    Sum = Sum + unique(key)
Next

MsgBox "This is the number of unique combinations: " & unique.Count
MsgBox "This is the number of duplicates: " & Sum - unique.Count
End Sub
```